# How to get BlockProvider recognized in my flutter project?

Tags: flutter, bloc

So, I'm trying out the BLOCK pattern recently and after having imported the block_pattern package in my pubsec yaml file like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  bloc_pattern: ^2.2.2+3
  rxdart:
```

Now, I have establish a class called CartListBloc as an extend of BlockBase

```
class CartListBloc extends BlocBase {
  CartListBloc();
  //etc...
```

When I try to put a BlockProvider in the main class it isn't recognized by the IDE despite having the correct imports.

```
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'bloc/cartListBloc.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlockProvider( // here it doesn't recognize BlockProvider
      blocs: [

      ],
      child:
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the `k` in `BlocProvider`

```
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'bloc/cartListBloc.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider( // remove the K
      blocs: [

      ],
      child:
    );
  }
}
```